# Value of address. Gives exception

Tags: c, printf

I am trying to print a piece of memory on a microcontroller.

It complaines about the line:

```
stringLength += sprintf(buffer + stringLength, "0x%X, ", *(startAddress + i));
```

due to the:

```
*(startAddress + i)
```

Why is this not working? Should it not just give me the value at the address?

Working on a ARM microcontroller and it jumps to HardFault_Handler() (which usually indicates illegal memory access).

How can I get the value at the memory location else wise?

**Entire function:**

```
void printMemory(uint32_t *startAddress, uint32_t lengthInBytes)
{
    uint32_t stringLength = 0;
    uint32_t i;
    char buffer[1000];
    uint32_t start = (uint32_t) startAddress;

    for (i = start; i < (start + lengthInBytes); i++)
    {
        if ((i % 10) == 0)
        {
            stringLength += sprintf(buffer + stringLength, "\r\n");
        }

        stringLength += sprintf(buffer + stringLength, "0x%X, ", *(startAddress + i));
    }

    //Add line termination.
    stringLength += sprintf(buffer + strlen(buffer), "%c", '\0');

    //Printf buffer.
    printf("%s", &buffer[0]);
}
```

**EDIT:**

Working example:

```
void printMemory(uint32_t startAddress, uint32_t lengthInBytes)
{
    uint32_t i;
    char buffer[1000];
    uint32_t stringLength = 0;
    uint8_t *start;

    //Create a uint8_t pointer to address.
    start = (uint8_t *) startAddress;

    for (i = 0; i < lengthInBytes; i++)
    {
        if ((i % 10) == 0)
        {
            stringLength += sprintf(buffer + stringLength, "\r\n");
        }

        stringLength += sprintf(buffer + stringLength, "0x%X, ", *(start + i));
    }

    //Add line termination.
    stringLength += sprintf(buffer + strlen(buffer), "%c", '\0');

    //Printf buffer.
    printf("%s", &buffer[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a mistake:

`i` starts at `start` which is `startAddress`, so at the first iteration you are fetching:

```
*(startAddress + startAddress)
```

Comment: Goddamnit... Thank you! =)

Comment: @Phataas On top of that, you are using a byte index against a uint32_t pointer, which means you are reading 3 bytes past the end of the buffer.